# implementing push_back on dynamically allocated memory for an array gives MEMORY LEAK

Tags: c++

Trying to dynamically implement an array in C++ with the following function.

I am not sure if the newArray needs to be deleted but right now it gives a memleak.

```
    void DynamicArray::push_back(Element e)
{
    if (arraySize == arrayCapacity) // Resizing is necessary
    {
        // Update private variables
        if (arrayCapacity == 0)
        {
            arrayCapacity += 2;
        }
        else
        {
            arrayCapacity *= 2;
        }
        Element* newArray = new Element[arrayCapacity]; // Make a new array
        for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        {
            newArray[i] = dynamicArray[i]; // Copy over old data
        }

        delete [] dynamicArray; // Remove the old array (prevent memory leak)
        dynamicArray = nullptr;
        dynamicArray = newArray;
        newArray = nullptr;
        delete [] newArray;
    }

    if (arraySize < arrayCapacity) // No resizing needed
    {
        dynamicArray[arraySize] = e; // With x items are in the array, the new item has an index of x
        arraySize += 1;
    }

}
```

seems to give a memory leak

Comment: [Related](http://coderscentral.blogspot.com/2012/08/c-dynamic-arrays.html).

Comment: Seems fine.. how do you know its a memory leak? Rule of three implemented? (or is it rule of five now?) Destructor, assignment operator and copy constructor?

Comment: Any reason not to use `std::vector`, which is already a dynamic array?

Comment: @Lebeau: Yes I am conscious of std::vector.

Comment: Can you show us the destructor, copy constructor and assignment operator for `DynamicArray`?  It's probable that one of these is causing a problem, but your leak checking tool is reporting the problem where the allocation is happening.

Comment: @Karthik Element DynamicArray::pop_back()
{
 if (arraySize <= 0)
 {
  throw std::out_of_range ("Out of range.");
 }
 arraySize -= 1;
 Element returnVal = dynamicArray[arraySize]; // Store the last value
 Element* newArray = new Element[arrayCapacity]; // The updated array will have the original capacity - 1
 for (int i = 0; i < (arraySize); i++)
 {
   newArray[i] = dynamicArray[i];
 }
 // Update private variables
 
 
 delete [] dynamicArray;
 dynamicArray = newArray;
 //newArray = nullptr;
 //delete [] newArray;
 return returnVal;
} is the only other function where it might cause the leak.

Comment: Shouldn't `arraySize` be incremented? (Apart from, probably, _not_ allocating `2x` `arrayCapacity` in `Element* newArray = new Element[arrayCapacity*2];`).

Comment: @ChrisZhang comment section is the wrong place to put up code more than 1 line, please add that to your question.

Comment: @PetrBudnik I believe this is just the housekeeping part of the `push_back` not the actual `push` section that would come after, notice that there is no assignment shown

Comment: @ChrisZhang All of my concerns still remain unanswered, also `dynamicArray = nullptr;` is not needed, and `newArray = nullptr;delete [] newArray;` is not needed, deleting `newArray` without the `nullptr` assign will cause a crash in the next line, deleting with it does nothing

Comment: Ok, I think, it's time to ask the OP: how did you determine it gives a memory leak?

Comment: @Karthik, sorry, I've changed the code per what you wanted. I'm still getting 1 block of memory leak with valgrind.

Comment: @ChrisZhang my first comment, [Rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) implemented?

Comment: No, it wasn't needed.

Comment: @ChrisZhang How do you determine it isnt needed? Because it is. Do you have a destructor atleast? If not that is the reason for the leak.

Comment: the destructor simply contains " delete [] dynamicArray; " and i'm assuming since dynamicArray gets to contian the address of the memory block of newArray, this deletes newArray as well.

Comment: Hold on, by `memory block` you mean you have an extra **entire array** leaking? If so, I'd look at copy-constructor and assignment operator first.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has no description

Comment: Original version available at:  http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18862448/revisions

Answer (score 1):

```
             arrayCapacity *= 2;
        }
        Element* newArray = new Element[arrayCapacity*2];
```

This causes your array to be much larger than your `arrayCapacity` this could be causing issues elsewhere.

It should just be

```
 Element* newArray = new Element[arrayCapacity];
```

p.s. If this isnt causing *the* issue, let me know and ill make this a comment, but it is a bug to fix nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

You allocate 2x elements:

```
Element* newArray = new Element[arrayCapacity*2]; // Make a new array
```

I assume, need:

```
Element* newArray = new Element[arrayCapacity]; // Make a new array
```